# IONIC 2 : Error: Unexpected token: name (Players) www/build/main.js at line 26325, col 4, pos 888867

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, uglifyjs

I tried to run "**ionic cordova run android --prod**" but I've got the following error in my terminal.

> [19:33:28] uglifyjs started ...  [WARN] Error occurred during command
>   execution from a CLI plugin (@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova). Your plugins
>   may be out of date. Error: Unexpected token: name (Players) in
>   /Volumes/Macintosh Data/IONIC_PROJECT/hukulele/www/build/main.js at
>   line 26325, col 4, pos 888867 Here is my Players class :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class Players{
    players: {name: string}[];

    addPlayer(player: {name: string}){
        this.players.push(player);
    }

    getPlayers(){
        return this.players.slice();
    }

    setPlayers(liste: {name: string}[]){
        this.players = liste;
    }

    initPlayers(){
        this.players = [{"name":""},{"name":""},{"name":""},{"name":""},{"name":""}];
    }
}
```

And the main.js file at line 26325 :

```
let Players = class Players {
    addPlayer(player) {
        this.players.push(player);
    }
    getPlayers() {
        return this.players.slice();
    }
    setPlayers(liste) {
        this.players = liste;
    }
    initPlayers() {
        this.players = [{ "name": "" }, { "name": "" }, { "name": "" }, { "name": "" }, { "name": "" }];
    }
};
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

Try to update tsconfig.json and set 
target: "es5"

I had mine set to es6

Refer to this: https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/issues/853